# Erro ao carregar informações da base de dados para um datagridview por meio do Entity Framework

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework, winforms, linq-to-entities

Meu projeto possui quatro classes:

```
public class Manifestacao
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string NumeroChamado { get; set; }
        public string DataHoraReg { get; set; }
        public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
        public Usuario UsuarioRespReg { get; set; }

        public List<Conteudo> Conteudos { get; set; }
    }

public class Conteudo
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoria { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string DataHoraReg { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public long ManifestacaoId { get; set; }
    public Manifestacao Manifestacao { get; set; }

}

public class Cliente
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Empresa { get; set; }
    public string Contato { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Ramal { get; set; }
    public string Celular { get; set; }
}

public class Usuario
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Apelido { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

}
```

Preciso preencher um datagridview com algumas informações da base de dados que foram persistidas por meio do Entityframework: Conteudo.Categoria, Conteudo.SubCategoria, Conteudo.Descrição, Conteudo.Status, Cliente.Empresa e Usuario.Nome

Desabilitei o LazyLoading na classe Context:

```
public class EFContext : DbContext
{
    public EFContext() : base("Pos_Venda_SAC")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Database.SetInitializer<EFContext>(
        new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFContext>()
        );
    }
    public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Conteudo> Conteudos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Manifestacao> Manifestacoes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Destinatario> Destinatarios { get; set; }
}
```

Com base na documentação do EF no [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) tentei usar a classe abaixo (GetConteudos()) para ler a base de dados, mas no datagridview aparecem as colunas com os nomes dos itens da classe Conteudo, mas as informações que deveriam ser associadas com as demais classes não aparecem.

```
public IList<Conteudo> GetConteudos()
{
    using (var context = new EFContext())
    {
        return context.Conteudos.Include(m => m.Manifestacao.Cliente).Include(u => u.Manifestacao.UsuarioRespReg.Nome).ToList();
    }
}
```

Faltou configurar alguma coisa?

Comment: Como você tá fazendo o _binding_ da lista pro grid?

Comment: Voce pode fazer e deve um linq que extraia essas colunas, porque o datagridview nao trabalha com dados complexos. Ou então crie um viewmodel e.resolva esse.problema.

Comment: @LINQ  dgvListagem.DataSource = GetConteudos();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai precisar retornar propriamente os dados que devem ser apresentados no `DataGridView` porque este controle não vai resolver tipos complexos.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
var dados = GetConteudos().Select(x => new 
                           {
                               Status = x.Status,
                               Empresa = Conteudo.Manifestacao.Cliente.Empresa,
                               // e assim por diante
                           }).ToList();

dgvListagem.DataSource = dados;
```

Comment: Perfeito, @LINQ! Problema resolvido! Muito obrigado! Só uma pequena dúvida... Fiz um teste e reabilitei o LazyLoading adicionando o virtual nas declarações e comentei a linha //this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; e mesmo assim o datagridview continuou exibindo os dados corretamente. O certo não seria deixar de exibir? Estou começando a usar o EntityFramework e por isso a curiosidade... rs

Comment: Não, @Leandro. O LazyLoading não tem nada a ver com a exibição dos dados. Ele só serve para carregar as entidades relacionadas sob demanda.

Comment: Certo. Obrigado!